# Is there a way to call DialogFlow v2 api using Enity Name instead of Entity Id?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home

Previous version of DialogFlow api was working on both Entity_Name/Entity_Id but v2 is supporting only Entity_Id. Now, Is there a way to call DialogFlow v2 api using Enity Name instead of Entity Id?